# Why my linked list only print the last entry?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to ask to user for a word and then save it on a linked list, since I'm on a loop. The problem is that it only print my last word instead of all the words that I introduced one by one. What am I doing wrong?

My main it's not exactly like this because I have a lot more code since I'm working with threads, but I am 100% sure that the problem are on the code that I'm posting.

EDITED

```
typedef struct data_msg msg, *p_msg;
struct data_msg {
    char topic[50];
    char title[50];
    char body[1000];
    int duration;
    p_msg next;
};

p_msg save_msg(p_msg pm, char topic[50], char title[50], char body[1000]){

    p_msg new, aux;

    new = malloc(sizeof(msg));

    if(new == NULL){
        printf("\n[ERROR] Memory allocation.");
        exit(0);
    }

    strcpy(new->topic, topic);
    strcpy(new->title, title);
    strcpy(new->body, body);
    new->next = NULL;

    if(pm == NULL)
        pm = new;
    else{
        aux = pm;
        while(aux->next != NULL)
            aux = aux->next;
        aux->next = new;
    }

    free(new);

    return pm;
}

int main(){
      char topic[50], title[50], body[1000];
        p_msg list = NULL;

        do{
            scanf("%s", topic);

            list = save_msg(list, topic, title, body);  

        } while(strcmp(topic, "exit") != 0);

    while(list != NULL){
                printf("=> %s\n", list->topic);
                list = list->next;
        }

    return 1;
```

Comment: Do you mind translating your variable names and strings into English?

Comment: @JL2210 Edit done!

Comment: Thank you. This makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're freeing memory that you're still using!

```
pmessage armazena_msg(pmessage pm, char *topic, char *title, char *company){

    pmessage new = malloc(sizeof(message));

    // populate this new item, copy things in

    // now link into the linked list
    if(pm == NULL)
        pm = new;
    else{
        pmessage tmp = pm;
        while(tmp->next != NULL)
            tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = new;
    }

//  free(new);      // BOOM!

    return pm;
}
```

The `pm` you're returning always includes the memory you allocated and initialized, either directly if it's the first one, or hooked into the list, but then when you free it, this memory is given back to the OS.

Then in a *second* call, there's a fair chance that the original memory - which was all set up nicely for you - is returned again, so the list ends up pointing to itself.

Comment out the `free()` and this ought to work as you expect.

**EDIT** there's still probably a bug: I believe you should test for `exit` before linking the message into the list unless you want `"exit"` added literally to the list as well.

Comment: I already tried comment the "free" line but it doesn't worked. I updated my main with my real code so you can understand my problem better (I hope!)

Comment: Can you explain what doesn't work? That `free()` was *killing* the program; how does it fail now?

Comment: Made no change. If I enter the word "one" prints "one", but then if I input the word "two" it only prints "two" and I'm expecting to print "one two"

Comment: Wait - that's not how the loop works. It only prints the results once you enter "exit", which marks the end of data entry.

Comment: Your right! Maybe I didn't saved the program. Thanks for your help!